# Undefined array key "startcolumn"

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to display a group of fields in TCPDF. I can display them by this code (without TCPDF) :

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ( $group as $v) : ?>                                         
          <tr>
                                                    <br>
                                                        
                                                   <td style = "widht:20%">Tahun       : </td>
                                                   <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['tahun']; ?></td>
                                                   <br>
                                                   <td style = "widht:20%">Kegiatan    : </td>
                                                   <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['kegiatan']; ?></td>
                                                   <br>
                                                   <td style = "widht:20%">Lokasi      : </td>
                                                   <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['lokasi']; ?></td>
                                                       
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php $i++; ?>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
    
                                            <br><br>
```

but I get error ' Undefined array key "startcolumn" ' in TCPDF (report.php) :

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
                                            <?php foreach ( $group as $v) : ?>                                              
                                                <tr>
                                                <tr>                                                    
                                                <td style = "widht:20%">Tahun       : </td>
                                                <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['tahun']; ?></td>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td style = "widht:20%">Kegiatan    : </td>
                                               <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['kegiatan']; ?></td>
                                                <tr>
                                              <td style = "widht:20%">Lokasi      : </td>
                                               <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['lokasi']; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php $i++; ?>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            <tr><tr>
```

Could anybody help me, please ?

---

This is my complete report.php

```
<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Laporan</title>
          </head>
          <style>
                .tabel {
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                }
                .tabel td {                 
                    border-style:ridge;
                }
          </style>
          <body>
            <h1 style="text-align:center;">DAFTAR RIWAYAT HIDUP</h1>
            <form action="<?= route_to('laporan', $result['id']) ?>"  method="post"><tr>
             
                                <table class="tabel">
                                    <colgroup>
                                        <col span="1" style="width: 40%;">
                                        <col span="1" style="width: 2%;">
                                        <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">                                                                                                      
                                    </colgroup>                                  
                                    <tbody>
                                            
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">1.Posisi yang diusulkan</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%"><?= $result['posisi'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">2.Nama Perusahaan</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%"><?= $result['perusahaan'] ?></td>
                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">3.Nama Personil</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%"><?= $result['nama'] ?></td>
                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">4.Tempat/tgl.lahir</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%"><?= $result['ttl'] ?></td>
                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%;">5.No. NPWP</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%; border:none">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%; border:none"><?= $result['no_npwp'] ?></td>
                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">6.No. Telp.</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%"><?= $result['no_telp'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">7. Pendidikan : </td>
                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Jurusan Pendidikan</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['ijazahS1'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Tempat/Universitas</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['s1_univ'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Tahun Tamat/Lulus</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['s1_thn'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Jurusan Pendidikan</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['ijazahS2'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Tempat/Universitas</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['s2_univ'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Tahun Tamat/Lulus</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['s2_thn'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>    
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Jurusan Pendidikan</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['ijazahS3'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Tempat/Universitas</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['s3_univ'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style = "width:40%">    -Tahun Tamat/Lulus</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:2%">:</td>
                                                    <td style = "width:50%">    <?= $result['s3_thn'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <label class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label" style="width: 20px;">Pengalaman</label>        
                                            <tr>
                                            <?php $i = 1; ?>
                                            <?php foreach ( $group as $v) : ?>                                              
                                                <tr>
                                                    <tr>                                                    
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Tahun       : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['tahun']; ?></td>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Kegiatan    : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['kegiatan']; ?></td>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Lokasi      : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['lokasi']; ?></td>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Pengguna    : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['pengguna']; ?></td>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Perusahaan  : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['perusahaan']; ?></td>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Posisi      : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['posisi']; ?></td>                                                                                              
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Referensi      : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['referensi']; ?></td>                                                                                              
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Status      : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['status']; ?></td>                                                                                              
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Uraian      : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['uraian']; ?></td>                                                                                              
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td style = "widht:20%">Waktu      : </td>
                                                    <td style = "width:20%"><?= $v['waktu']; ?></td>                                                                                              
                                                    <tr>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php $i++; ?>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            <tr><tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You should post all the source code of the report.php

Comment: I just encountered a similar error message, which led me to validate the HTML output. I had an empty <tr></tr> table row at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, just add this code to jump to the new line
`<tr><td></td></tr>`